# removing element from a ListModel removes wrong element

Tags: java, defaultlistmodel

I have no idea why it's happening, I'll look at other parts of my code if I need to but I really prefer it to be something else...

let's say I have the following items in my JList

> Beer
>
> Mercedes
>
> Coca Cola

and str == "Mercedes", it will remove everything but this item.

why?

```
for(int i=0;i<listModel.getSize();i++){
        if (listModel.elementAt(i).equals(str))
            listModel.remove(i);
    }
```

Comment: I tried breaking after I found the item I want to remove and it works,

now it works for me because I only need to remove 1 item everytime this loop runs, but what if I didn't?

I heared somewhere that you should duplicate the list to remove elements ... is that true? how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try that :

```
listModel.removeElement(str)
```

And don't forget to check Strings for null values !

Comment: I tried and crossed my fingers but it doesn't work :( ... I also tried removeElementAt, both those methods take int arguments (at least that's what eclipse says..)

Comment: I don't see this method in JList : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html. Are you sure your example is a JList, and not a java.util.List ?

Comment: DefaultListModel object

Comment: Well, actually there is a remove(int index) method in JList, my bad. I will update my answer accordingly